# WPF Performance monitor for Windows 8

Tags: wpf, performance, windows-8

I'm trying to monitor / find the biggest performance bottlenecks for my WPF application, and all the places I've been googling are saying "install the WPFPerf.msi", but to install that, I should install the Windows SDK 7.1 first, but the installation fails on Windows 8.

And WPFPerf has been removed from the Windows 8 SDK toolkit..

So is there any WPF performance monitoring tool that works in Windows 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the option to start a performance analysis from the Analyze menu in Visual Studio when in a WPF project. See this screenshot: [image: Performance analysis in Visual Studio 2012]

(This is from Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, with the [Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx) installed.)

Comment: Thanks! What a strange thing googling with words "WPF", "Performance analysis", "Windows 8" did not give anything that could have pointed my the right way. Anyway - thanks!